# how setup php project to install database through user interface

Tags: php, database, cakephp, installation

I have enough experience to build websites in PHP using CakePhp framework but now i'm trying to build website like others professional where GUI is given to user to configure/install website by providing host, database name, user name, password where website have 1 file called "install.php" it takes database detail to connect and create database.

Here my question comes ,when website prompt user to enter detail for database and after getting values for host, database name, user, password; we run databse.sql file to create database but after that how our project knows the user name,password, database name, host to connect beacause normally we write database credentials in file of php to configure so in this way how we handle connection between our PHP website and database.

one solution i'm thinking to write some keyword in database configuration file and replace them with user provided detail.

If you have better solution then please guide me.

Comment: I think it work same as you are thinking. Basically there should be one file name it settings.php, add variables in that file then replace all your variables value with user inputs and make sure this settings.php file is common so variables and all configuration can be called in all php pages.

Comment: thanks for such advice

Comment: And one more thing when running installation firstly you have to check if those variable are set or not, else when you migrate your existing website it will create issue and ask you for fresh installation every time.

Comment: really nice tip. i will handle it by giving choice to user if he want to create database or he already has, then we will save only configuration setting and would not run database script. i found good solution to handle config.php. you can see this in answer. @JiteshNK

Answer (score 2):

i found answer for this

config.php:

```
return array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'not-defined',
);
```

setting.php:

```
$config = include 'config.php';
$config['username']= 'root';
file_put_contents('config.php', '<?php return ' . var_export($config, true) . ';');
```

Updated config.php now contains the following:

```
return array(
     'host' => 'localhost',
     'username' => 'root',
);
```

you can add add/update other attributes in same way.